# build error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion' when building from source using bazel

Tags: grpc

I follow [grpc building instructions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md) using bazel, and after the step `bazel build :all` I got the errors shown as follows

```
ERROR: /home/username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_username/36f83adb686bb580874d961cfbeaeeac/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/BUILD.bazel:104:11: Compiling src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): clang failed: error executing command (from target @com_google_protobuf//src/google/protobuf/compiler:protoc_lib) /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin/clang -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 92 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:32:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/_virtual_includes/command_line_interface/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h:52:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/port.h:53:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:32:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/_virtual_includes/command_line_interface/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h:55:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:33:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/_virtual_includes/cpp/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/generator.h:43:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/_virtual_includes/code_generator/google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.h:49:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:33:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/_virtual_includes/cpp/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/generator.h:46:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:34:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/_virtual_includes/csharp/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_generator.h:40:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:35:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/_virtual_includes/java/google/protobuf/compiler/java/generator.h:45:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:36:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/_virtual_includes/java/google/protobuf/compiler/java/kotlin_generator.h:41:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:37:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/_virtual_includes/objectivec/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/generator.h:40:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:64:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/_virtual_includes/lite/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:46:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/_virtual_includes/lite/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h:45:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:37:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/_virtual_includes/objectivec/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/generator.h:40:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:64:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/_virtual_includes/lite/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:56:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:37:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/_virtual_includes/objectivec/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/generator.h:40:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:78:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:37:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/_virtual_includes/objectivec/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/generator.h:43:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:38:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/php/_virtual_includes/php/google/protobuf/compiler/php/php_generator.h:35:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/php/_virtual_includes/names/google/protobuf/compiler/php/names.h:39:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:38:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/php/_virtual_includes/php/google/protobuf/compiler/php/php_generator.h:40:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:39:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/_virtual_includes/python/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h:44:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:11:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:39:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/_virtual_includes/python/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h:44:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:24:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/_virtual_includes/io/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h:140:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:39:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/_virtual_includes/python/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h:44:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:25:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/arena.h:52:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/arena_align/google/protobuf/arena_align.h:85:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:39:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/_virtual_includes/python/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h:44:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:25:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/arena.h:53:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/arena/google/protobuf/arena_config.h:38:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:39:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/_virtual_includes/python/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h:44:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:25:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/arena.h:55:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/serial_arena.h:49:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/arena_cleanup/google/protobuf/arena_cleanup.h:46:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:39:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/_virtual_includes/python/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h:44:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_nowkt/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:25:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/arena.h:55:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/serial_arena.h:51:
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/protobuf_lite/google/protobuf/arenaz_sampler.h:42:
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/port_def/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:1009:32: error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
                               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
INFO: Elapsed time: 25.637s, Critical Path: 5.23s
INFO: 219 processes: 219 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (on VirtualBox 7.0)

gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

clang version: clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)

--

I have no idea how to fix it. Is there something I missed?

I expect it building without error. Thanks.

Comment: That source expects a newer gcc.  I'd just delete that source line.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've updated gcc and now `gcc --version` gives `gcc (Ubuntu 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~18.04) 13.1.0` but it still has `error: unknown warning group '-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion', ignored [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]` issue. What's go wrong?

Comment: It says it's running clang, not gcc.  I still say you should just delete the line.  That error is only issued if you're compiling for C++20.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04, but the grpc archive has many release versions (git branch --all), so I decided to find the latest version for my compiler (gcc --version has 7.5.0 for me), I did following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
cd grpc
git checkout v1.54.x
git submodule update --init
bazel build :all
```

For protobuf, you could check it out separately since grpc is only using the payload from protobuf I think. Now I use version 26.0 for protobuf, which works perfect in Ubuntu 18.04.